# ChromeDriver / Selenium not allowing gmail logins

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

There is nothing wrong with my code, however by the time I fill out the Username & Password and attempt to login, gmail blocks this because it detects that I am using an automated browser. I get the message below

[image]

There is really nothing too personal on this email, its a dummy email used by my company for testing purposes. We make use of the + annotation to create several unique addresses associated with it and I read somewhere this may be the reason why. Is there not a secure way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api)?

Comment: In my case, I need to click the email and then there will be an invitation link that I need to click in order to continue with the scenario. Is this something that can be done through the API? Maybe just the validation part to be able to log in?

Comment: *[shrug]*  I would imagine that's the very scenario that Google is trying to defend against.  They want actual human beings to be validating those accounts, not automated machines used by spammers and other bad actors.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I completely agree with that, its a double edged sword. There are a ton of business scenarios that interact with email so it would be nice to automate these scenarios. I can understand the decision however.

Comment: Can you configure mailhog on your app for dev purposes? Otherwise: look into connecting to gmail via api rather than UI.

Comment: @DMart connecting to the account via API would be fine as long as I can get into the account and access the emails. Would this be something I would do before I even launch the ChromeDriver?

Comment: Check the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78148407/3806036