# Problem to login Gmail account with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a Python code using Selenium to optimize tasks on Google Sites.

For this to be possible, you need to log into your Gmail account.

I can't log into the account because Google doesn't recognize the valid browser.

Any solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Gmail detects and blocks selenium, or automating software/bots in general, you need to find a workaround.

Comment: You'd want to use your default chrome profile which has signed into gmail. So user-data-dir within the options import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass bot detection with [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in `uc` mode.

First `pip install seleniumbase`. Then you can run:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
    sb.click('a[data-action="sign in"]')
    sb.type('input[type="email"]', "test123@gmail.com")
    sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
    sb.sleep(5)
    # sb.type('input[type="password"]', PASSWORD)
    # sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
```

Update the script with the info you need, then run with `python`. To access the raw driver from the script, use `sb.driver`.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a solution to unblock from google anti bot detection logic and successfully login into gmail after adding below line of codes while creating chrome driver instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)   

_driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

    # Initializing a list with two Useragents
    useragentarray = [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    ]

    for i in range(len(useragentarray)):
        # Setting user agent iteratively as Chrome 108 and 107
        _driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setUserAgentOverride", {"userAgent": useragentarray[i]})
        print(_driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
        # _driver.get("https://www.httpbin.org/headers")
```

Then, I tried to login into gmail and it worked.

Comment: For the record, I was talking about the YouTube video.

Comment: Thanks again. I deleted the video link.