# Selenium Google Login Block using webdriver options

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I saw following posts.

Selenium Google Login Block
[Selenium Google Login Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117232/selenium-google-login-block)
Problem to login Gmail account with Selenium Python
[Problem to login Gmail account with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74383141/problem-to-login-gmail-account-with-selenium-python/78148407#78148407)

My goal is to login google through google colab.

I used code below

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
# Initializing a list with two Useragents
useragentarray = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.6312.58 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.6312.58 Safari/537.36",
]
for i in range(len(useragentarray)):
    # Setting user agent iteratively as Chrome 108 and 107
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setUserAgentOverride", {"userAgent": useragentarray[i]})
    print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
    driver.get("https://www.httpbin.org/headers")
```

Then, I got follow headers.

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Host": "www.httpbin.org", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.6312.58 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-65fe5243-35dffc7e6b07d54d014091e4"
  }
}
```

Then, tried to login.
But google detected as bot.

What should I do?